# Is any prime test verifiable?

Tags: proof-verification, prime-numbers, computational-complexity

Factoring a large number $x$ by trial division is a lot of work, but if you succeed, you get two factors, which anyone can easily multiply together to make $x$: an easily checked proof that $x$ is in fact composite.

Is there any test for primes that produces a similar artifact? That is: having done the work—trial division or the Lucas-Lehmer test or any other test—and determined that some large $x$ is prime, is there any way to use that work to produce a proof that others can verify without basically doing all the work over again?

(I think this can be made precise, as a complexity question—is there any $S \subseteq \mathbb N$ such that prime testing on $S$ is a  harder problem than checking a certain kind of proof—but it's a bit beyond me.)

Comment: Look up [primality certificate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primality_certificate)

Comment: Also, (as mentioned [in the Wikipedia article linked by @RobertIsrael](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primality_certificate#Impact_of_%22PRIMES_is_in_P%22)), since primality can be checked in polynomial time, the complexity question will be hard to formalize in a non-trivial way. (I.e., you'd need quite fine-grained complexity there, and getting an unconditional statement seems unlikely as of now.)

Comment: OK, the relevant search term is [certifying algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Certifying_algorithm), and given PRIMES is in P, this is hardly a complexity theory question. It's hard enough to find a working programmer who cares about the difference between $O(n^3)$ and $O(n^6)$. ;) Thanks!

Comment: @JasonOrendorff Do you really claim that it does not matter in practice whether an algorithm is $O(n^3)$ or $O(n^6)$ ?

Comment: No, that's not what I said or what I think. To me it's *mathematically* interesting to define "certifying algorithm" in terms of these complexity classes within P and see what there is; but I don't expect anyone else to care.